# There is a problem in converting jar to exe (image issue)

Tags: java, jsmooth

I'm making a GUI program with JAVA
And I want to show image while program is running

**It runs well on eclips**
then I want to convert exe file, 
so I export the projects as runnable jar and us jsmooth
but it doesn't work as an exe file

```
introBackground = new 
ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/intro.jpg")).getImage();
```

If I convert as console program,
It says,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at test.Intro.<init>(Intro.java:31)
at test.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Comment: Remove .getImage()

Comment: Is the images folder inside the workspace?